# C# Json.NET Camel Case Complex Object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to serialize an object as camelCase and I'm finding that only the objects at the root level are correctly camelCased. Everything below the root level is coming as PascalCase. I'm writing a console application using Json.NET 12.0.3 and .NET Framework 4.0.

```
public class Deal
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PublicId> PublicIds { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PublicId
{
    public string IdType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize I'm using:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deal, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd",
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
```

The result json looks like:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "Deal 1",
  "publicIds": [
    {
      "IdType": "ID1",
      "Value": "A12"
    },
    {
      "IdType": "ID2",
      "Value": "B12"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the values for IdType and Value are not correctly serialied in camelCase but rather are serialized in PascalCase. There are situations where I'll need to change the serialization between the default PascalCase and camelCase so I won't be able to use JsonProperty annotations to force camelCase during serialization. Additionally I'd like to stick to Json.NET as the only json library for my project.

Is there a clean way to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: are you sure theres no `JsonProperty` attributes anywhere?

Comment: running this in LinqPad produces json with all properties camelcased.  There's some information missing that is causing your issue.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PuyjDW)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I noticed that your `Deal` class does not initialize `PublicIds`. In that case the code should actually throw an error.

However, your code that specifies the contract solver `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` is correct.

The following is a console code that seems to return proper `JSON` value.

```cs
public class Deal
{
    public Deal()
    {
        PublicIds = new List<PublicId>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PublicId> PublicIds { get; set; }
}

public class PublicId
{
    public string IdType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the console if the try the code below it seems to yield the desired result.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var deal = new Deal();
    deal.Name = "Deal 1";
    deal.PublicIds.Add(new PublicId { IdType = "ID1", Value = "A12" });
    deal.PublicIds.Add(new PublicId { IdType= "ID2", Value= "B12"});

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deal, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    });

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output by the code:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "Deal 1",
  "publicIds": [
    {
      "idType": "ID1",
      "value": "A12"
    },
    {
      "idType": "ID2",
      "value": "B12"
    }
  ]
}
```